# Looking for a query to group by each hour and collect users info

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I want to create a query that can give me the user id's message count + the hour that it has been posted.

I have a hours table with 0-23 hours, I have a history table with messages that users posted + the date_added.

Now I want to create a result that will show me:

- Each hour should have ALL the users from user table
- The count of messages this user has posted even if there are no records in the history table with the user_id

I have tried this query, the only thing that is wrong is that it doesn't show every hour's userId

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS messages, h.hour AS `Hour`, c.user_id, p.name
FROM history c
  INNER JOIN users p ON c.user_id = p.user_id
  RIGHT JOIN hours h ON h.hour = HOUR(c.`date_added`)
    AND YEAR(`date_added`) = '2019' AND MONTH(`date_added`) = '03' AND DAY(`date_added`) = '06'
GROUP BY h.hour, c.user_id
ORDER BY h.hour ASC;
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5c60d5b

-- EDIT thanks for all the queries!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're after **all users for all hours** regardless if they have messages or not, the code below is probably what you're looking for. It contains two subqueries to allow the message counts table to be added onto a full list of users and hours.

```
SELECT messages, h.hour AS `hour`, h.user_id, h.name
FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS messages, HOUR(c.`date_added`) as `hour`, c.user_id, p.name
  FROM users p
  INNER JOIN history  c
  ON c.user_id = p.user_id
  WHERE YEAR(`date_added`) = '2019' AND MONTH(`date_added`) = '03' AND DAY(`date_added`) = '06'
  GROUP BY HOUR(c.`date_added`), c.user_id, p.name
  ) z
  right join
  (
    SELECT h.hour, u.user_id, u.name
    FROM hours h
    CROSS JOIN users u
  ) h ON h.hour = z.hour
      AND h.user_id = z.user_id
 ORDER BY hour
```

Comment: Hi matt, thanks for this query, I've tried all queries here and your seems to be the fastest one!

Just a small question, do you think its possible to return the username instead of the user id ? The SELECT on `name` does return NULL whereas the user_id would return the correct value

Comment: Sorry about that - Was pulling the name from the wrong table - that should now be fixed!

Answer (score 1):

With a cross join for `hours` and `users` and a left join to `history`:

```
select 
  t.hour, t.user_id, t.name, sum(history_id is not null) messages
from (select * from hours cross join users) t
left join (
  select * from history
  where
    year(date_added) = 2019 and month(date_added) = 3 and day(date_added) = 6
) h 
on h.user_id = t.user_id and t.hour = hour(h.date_added)
group by t.hour, t.user_id, t.name
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=d3e60b68d68567788d7a3a34ede1faaf).
Results:

```
> hour | user_id | name  | messages
>   .. |........ |...... |.........
>   14 |       4 | test4 |        0
>   15 |       1 | test  |        0
>   15 |       2 | test2 |        0
>   15 |       3 | test3 |        0
>   15 |       4 | test4 |        0
>   16 |       1 | test  |        1
>   16 |       2 | test2 |        0
>   16 |       3 | test3 |        5
>   16 |       4 | test4 |        8
>   17 |       1 | test  |        0
>   .. |........ |...... |.........
```

I added `user_id = 4` in the `users` table of your sample data because it was included in `history`.

Comment: Thanks forpas, I've never heard of cross join's before. Simple yet effective. Thanks!

Comment: @MaikelSimons if it is working consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For having every possible combination between two unrelated tables you could use `CROSS JOIN`. As such the query below achieves --*"Each hour should have ALL the users from user table"*:

```
SELECT h.hour, u.user_id
FROM hours h
CROSS JOIN users u
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using left join nad hour date_added  in group by

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS messages,  hour(date_added)  , c.user_id, p.name
FROM history c
 INNER JOIN users p ON c.user_id = p.user_id
  LEFT JOIN hours h ON h.hour = hour(date_added) 
AND YEAR(`date_added`) = '2019' AND MONTH(`date_added`) = '03' AND DAY(`date_added`) = '06'
GROUP BY hour(date_added) , c.user_id
ORDER BY h.hour ASC;
```